# Why does screen = pygame.display.set_mode() can do screen.blit()?

Tags: python, class, module, pygame, game-development

I saw a piece of code like this one:

```
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode(...)`

Screen.blits(...)
```

My question is, how we should call the `blits` method from the variable screen. Is it because `display` is a class and screen becomes an object? However, if this is true then shouldn't we have to do instead `screen = pygame.display()`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [manual](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) for `pygame.display.set_mode()`, you can see that it returns a `Surface` type object, so in effect it "constructs" a new object.

The [manual](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) for the PyGame `Surface` object lists both `blit()` and `blits()` member functions.  This is why it's correct to say `Screen.blit(...)` as in your question code.

The code `pygame.Display` represents the name of a class, but it is not directly used like this.